# Correct particle usage: を or は?

Tags: translation, particles, particle-は, particle-を

I want to say, "Are you sure you want to remove Alex?" Do I use `を` or `は`?

```
    アレックスを削除してもよろしいですか。
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1: It's better to use `を` I think.

Reason: If you say `アレックスは削除してもよろしいですか`, people will think there are other things/persons that supposed to be removed sometime. In other words, `は` is just not natural.

2: `スタート` is correct to use in this circumstance.

Reason: `スタート` is widely used especially in games and competitions.

Comment: I put (2) in a separate question as per senshin's suggestion. Sorry about that. Feel free to copy and paste your answer to (2) here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15955/1346