# Should I use スタート for "start a new game" or something else?

Tags: word-choice, loanwords

I want to say, "Are you sure you want to start a new game?" (I'm developing a game for Japanese users, and this question is asked when it finishes.) I'm not sure whether `スタート` is the correct word to use in this context or whether there exists a Japanese word that should be used instead.

> 新規ゲームを**スタート**してもよろしいですか。

Comment: はじめ has a meaning which reads as'(n-adv,n-t) beginning, start, origin, (P)', so you could use that. But not in your current sentence structure (I believe). I can't see a huge problem with your use of スタート, it certainly makes grammatical sense to me, and I now that スタート can be used in speech to indicate the beginning of something.

Comment: FWIW, that's the exact sentence I came up with in my head after just reading the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

スタート would certainly be understood in the context you've got.

Expanding a bit, if it's just an option on a starting splash screen (e.g. "1P Start", "2P Start"), you probably don't even really need to put it in Katakana.

If you're doing a game with a saved game feature, however, more often what I tend to see is the pair はじめから (from the beginning) and つづきから (continue from where you left off).

Comment: The OP's context, if I understand correctly, is that *after the game is complete*, they ask the player if they want to start a new game.  They've supplied the sentence they've come up with for this context.